# Counts the occurrence of data in table1 based on presence of same data in table2 and group summary by year and month

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

**Step 1** - Count all the rows in `t1` where `field1` is present (i.e. not null) as `Count1` and group by year and month.

```
SELECT
  Year(t1.date) AS Year,
  Month(t1.date) AS Month,
  Count(t1.field1) As Count1,
FROM t1
GROUP BY Year(t1.date), Month(t1.date)
```

**Step 2** - Count all the rows in `t1` where the value for `t1.field1` is **NOT IN** `t2.field1` as `Count2` and group by year and month.

```
SELECT
  Year(t1.date),
  Month(t1.date),
  Count(*) t1.field1 AS Count2,
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
  WHERE ISNULL t2.field1
GROUP BY Year(t1.date), Month(t2.date)
```

**Step 3** - Show the results of both counts above in a table with `Year(t1.date)` as row header and `Month(t1.date)` as column header with the results of `Count1` and `Count2` nested under each month.

I don't have any code to show you for Step 3 because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I wish I could... don't know where to begin.. I've put some code that almost* works except it only involves one table...

Comment: #4 is what's called a "pivot table". Mysql doesn't have them built in, but if you search SO for "mysql pivot" you'll find lots of questions and answers related to it.

Comment: It's still a pivot table, so my suggestion stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

> SELECT
>          STEP1.Total_Rows_S1, STEP1.Year_S1, STEP1.Month_S1, COUNT(*) as Remaining_Rows
>   FROM (
>               SELECT
>               Year(t1.date) AS Year_S1,
>               Month(t1.date) AS Month_S1,
>               Count(t1.field1) As Total_Rows_S1,
>               t1.field1 AS FS1
>               FROM t1
>               GROUP BY Year(t1.date), Month(t1.date)
>       )   AS STEP1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (STEP1.FS1 = t2.field1)
>        WHERE ISNULL t2.field1
>       GROUP BY STEP1.Year_S1, Month(t2.date)

Comment: Hi Joddy, that is good for selecting the data for step 2 above. But now I want to count the rows in that selection and compare it to the total number of rows, like a summary report. "How many records are there in total from table1?" and "How many records in table 1 are not in table2?" "Show me the results by year and month"

Comment: @BenJones - I was confused with the question, thought you just want to extract YEAR and MONTH from the result you have in STEP 3

Comment: @BenJones - I have edited the answer post. I am not sure it will work, but I hope you get the idea